# Syntax of FQL in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any one please tell me the syntax of using FQL in a rails application ?
I would like to use the code in my controller.
I have all the queries but need syntax to make it up and running.

Thank in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in Facebook API, you'd need to install a gem or plugin that provides an interface - or build the interactions by hand by rolling oyur own http requests. Here is a page that discusses it: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Using_Ruby_on_Rails_with_Facebook_Platform

Comment: o...I C;

Thanks anyways for the reply..
Is there any way to access number of posts  in a topic in public view in facebook??